# Can I use `-fno-implicit-templates` feature only for one template?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

Is it possible to forbid implicit instantiation, like `-fno-implicit-templates` does, but only for one template?

I have a problem with implicit instantiation of incomplete template, which causes compilation failure (part of implementation is hidden in source file, and I don't want to have it in other TUs). `-fno-implicit-templates` solves the problem, but at cost of problems with using STL and other templates.

Comment: You can use explicit template instantiation declaration (`extern template class X</*...*/>;` in header file) and definition (`extern template class X</*...*/>;` in source file) for such template.

Comment: Wow, that works! It's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much.

If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use explicit template instantiation. Put explicit template instantiation declaration `extern template class TemplateClass<ArgumentsSet>;` (where `ArgumentsSet` is a `TemplateClass` arguments set for which you want to avoid implicit instantiation in your code) in your header file (you can put such directive for several arguments sets if you want). Also put explicit template instantiation definition `template class TemplateClass<ArgumentsSet>;` in your source file to explicitly instantiate `TemplateClass` for `ArgumentsSet` in this translation unit.